# Who healed Obito?

Tags: naruto

I remember there was old man. But was it Madara? And shared his sharingan?

But Madara should have Rinnigan there, isn't it?

If that was Madara then why he was raised much younger later?

Comment: There must have been a pretty obvious answer if this got down voted, was there?

Comment: @MiharuDante I don't know where is it revealed that it was Madara so I can't say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the old man was Madara. His Rinnegan was already given away (to Nagato) by the time he found Obito.

Also, since Kabuto used Edo Tensei to revive he, he was revived with his body at his prime.

Comment: But he has two rinnegans?

Comment: @Heather: He had two Rinnegans, he gave away both, and implanted a replacement sharingan into one of his eyes. (which is what's seen when he rescues Obito)

Comment: And where did Madara get sharingans?

Comment: @Heather: He had an extra from somewhere, maybe from an older battle. It wasn't told where he got the replacement from.

Comment: Ah... Alike he wore a pair of eyes in the pocket... Just in case. May you point me when and why he gave rinnigans to Nagato?

Comment: @Heather if I recall right, he gave the Rinnegan to Nagato when he was a young child(don't remember the exact age), the reason is, I assume, that he already knew the details of the Tsuki no Me , thus his only chance to achieve it, it would've been gaining life by the Rinne Tensei(he had no power/liberty, plus he would've been dead)...so in this way, practically he started his whole plan